# How could I iterate over the elements of a list of tuples and get the elements as strings as a result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just trying to write a program which loads a workbook, iterates over the values of all the cells in two columns, format a string with the values read from those cells and writes the resulting formatted string to a new worksheet's column's cells.
My problem is that I cannot get the original values as strings to be able to format them with string operations.
The other problem is that if I could even format the string successfully, I also don't know how to write the resulting string values to the new worksheet's column A.

This only appends the last element of fiok to fiokstr as string.
Any idea why only the last element is appended?

```
for x in fiok:
    fiokstr = []
    for y in x:
        fiokstr.append(y)
```

Comment: Because `fiokstr = []` is inside loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `fiokstr` outside the loop:

```py
fiokstr = []
for x in fiok:
    for y in x:
        fiokstr.append(y)
```

As it is, you're reassigning an empty list to it for every run through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I might be reading this wrong, but it looks like every time it iterates through `fiok`, `fiokstr` gets set back to an empty list. Try defining `fiokstr` outside of that outer for loop. Eg:

```
fiokstr = []
for x in fiok:
    newl = []
    for y in x:
        newl.append(y)
    fiokstr.append(newl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. That populated fiokstr appropriately, along with another list, ipstr (same number of entries in the two lists).

And why is the following?

When I run:

txt = []

```
for nev in fiokstr:
    text = "H_"+nev.capitalize()
    txt.append(text)
```

or

```
for cim in ipsrtr:
    text = "_UPS_"+cim.replace("/24", "")
    txt.append(text)
```

txt gets populated appropriately, but when I run:

```
for nev in fiokstr, cim in ipstr:

    text = "H_"+nev.capitalize()+"_UPS_"+cim.replace("/24", "")
    txt.append(text)
```

I get "NameError: name 'nev' is not defined", although previously worked as I wrote.

Thank you.